# is there any way to optimize stock by using statistic functions of php?

Tags: php

I was trying to get a right amount for a single product on stock for the current month, this would be based on the amount of sales of the previous months. I know it can't be done by averaging since there could be some discrepancies (a single customer could buy a much larger amount than average).

Here's the array I was trying to use:

```
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 1
)
```

Each position represents a month and their respective sales of a given product. I think that some statistical functions described in http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php could be useful, but I don't understand much of statistics.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Comment: this looks like a  a math\business logic question, not a programming one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.trader.php description and methods. There is a set of functions for moving average, like simple moving average: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trader-sma.php

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot more variables to consider than just amount sold by month. for example, what is the item's shelf life? What is the order-to-restock time?  Based on your comment "a single customer could buy a much larger amount than average" I'd say stock the maximum ever sold which is easy:

```
max($salesArray);
```